# Change CSS on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I for the life of me cannot get this to work. I am trying to run a simple script that changes the display property of a logo. It is set to none initially and it should switch to block once the browser is scrolled down 170px. This is the script I'm using

```
var $logo = $('#mainlogo');
$(document).scroll(function() {
$logo.css({display: $(this).scrollTop()>170 ? "block":"none"});
});
```

It's not registering any errors in the console. You can check it running here. http://www.staywell.contravent.com the password is CV2014! Any help is much appreciated.

Is there any way to do this without a script? Purely CSS?

Comment: _“It's not registering any errors in the console”_ – So you don’t consider f.e. `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` to be an error …?

Comment: It seems you called `noConflict` since `$` is undefined. (Which is the error being thrown in console)

Comment: You're right, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: How do I get rid of noConflict?

Comment: i use "jquery waypoints" plugin for all such needs.

Comment: @Abs wouldn't I still have the same problem?

Comment: @jmkill - You can hunt down the offending `noConflict` call and remove it, redefine `$` as `jQuery` (`var $ = jQuery` above your `var $logo` statement) , or you can update your snippet of JS from `$('#mainLogo') to jQuery('#mainLogo'), $(document) to jQuery(document), and $(this) to jQuery(this)`

Comment: @JackPattishall I swapped in jQuery for the $ and that made it work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var $logo = $('#mainlogo');
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
   $logo.css({display: $(window).scrollTop() > 170 ? "block":"none"});
});
```

try wrapping your code in a self invoked function with a $ jQuery parameter:

```
(function($) {
    var $logo = $('#mainlogo');
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
       $logo.css({display: $(window).scrollTop() > 170 ? "block":"none"});
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: This still has the same undefined TypeError